# PHP undefined index database issues

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I am having issues with displaying the database table. My database table (activities) have the following value, ID (Primary Key), type, title, description and picture. I am trying to retrieve and display title,description and picture in a table format but is facing an  error

> "Notice: Undefined index: title, Notice: Undefined index: description
>   and Notice: Undefined index: picture"

which I am unable to solve it. 
Below are my php code:

```
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
           <div id="content">   
               <table><?php 
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "root";
                $password = "";
                $dbname = "sentosa_resort";

                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, 
               $dbname);
               // Check connection
               if ($conn->connect_error) {
                   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
               } 

                $query = "SELECT title,description,picture FROM activites"; 
                $result = $conn->query($sql);;

                 // start a table tag in the HTML

                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $description = $row['description'];
                   $picture = $row['picture'];
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $title . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $description . "</td>";
                     echo "<td>" . $picture . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                ?></table>
                </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: show your table structure too

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your code for an extra semi colon in line number 16...

OR

You can use `mysqli_fetch_row`

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                       <div id="content">   
                           <table>
        <?php 
                            $servername = "localhost";
                            $username = "root";
                            $password = "";
                            $dbname = "sentosa_resort";

                            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, 
                           $dbname);
                           // Check connection
                           if ($conn->connect_error) {
                               die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                           } 

                            $query = "SELECT title,description,picture FROM activites"; 
                            $result = $conn->query($query);

                             // start a table tag in the HTML

                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
                                $title = $row['0'];
                                $description = $row['1'];
                               $picture = $row['2'];
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>" . $title . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $description . "</td>";
                                 echo "<td>" . $picture . "</td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            ?>
    </table>
                            </div>
                      </div>
```

Comment: If he uses mysqli_fetch_array without specifying a second parameter, MYSQLI_BOTH is implicit, so he'll get both an index based and associative based array, so what the OP did is right.

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your code and that is:

```
 $query = "SELECT title,description,picture FROM activites";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);; // here is error
```

Please do change change the above error line similar to below:

```
$result = $conn->query($query);
```

Solution: Changed $sql to $query because your query string is stored in $query variable not $sql and removed extra semicolon

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code please check it

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
           <div id="content">   
               <table><?php 
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "root";
                $password = "";
                $dbname = "sentosa_resort";

                $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, 
               $dbname);


                $query = "SELECT title,description,picture FROM activites"; 
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);    


                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $description = $row['description'];
                   $picture = $row['picture'];
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $title . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $description . "</td>";
                     echo "<td>" . $picture . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                ?></table>
                </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are getting those Notices because you are using `mysqli_fetch_array()`, instead you need to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

If you want to continue using `mysqli_fetch_array()` then change the code to:

```
$title = $row[0];
$description = $row[1];
$picture = $row[2];
```

Comment: For fetch array what he did was right.. he should use fetch row for using your example..

Comment: And why not `mysqli_fetch_assoc`?

Comment: If he uses mysqli_fetch_array without specifying a second parameter, MYSQLI_BOTH is implicit, so he'll get both an index based and associative based array, so what the OP did is right.